# Get term frequencies within categories in R dictionary

Tags: r, text-mining, text-analysis, quanteda

I have a dictionary with multiple subcategories and I would like to find the most frequent words and bigrams within each subcategory using R.

I am using a large dataset but here's an example of what I have looks like:

```
s <-  "Day after day, day after day,
We stuck, nor breath nor motion;"

library(stringi)
x <- stri_replace_all(s, "", regex="<.*?>") 
x <- stri_trim(s)
x <- stri_trans_tolower(s) 

library(quanteda)
toks <- tokens(x) 
toks <- tokens_wordstem(toks) 

dtm <- dfm(toks, 
       tolower=TRUE, stem=TRUE,
       remove=stopwords("english"))

dict1 <- dictionary(list(a=c("day*", "week*", "month*"),
                    b=c("breath*","motion*")))

dict_dtm2 <- dfm_lookup(dtm, dict1, nomatch="_unmatched")                                 
tail(dict_dtm2)
```

This gives me the total frequencies per subcategory but not the frequency of each individual word within these subcategories. 
The results I am looking for would look something like this:

```
words(a)   freq
day         4
week        0
month       0

words(b)   freq
breath     1
motion     1
```

I would appreciate any help with that!

Comment: what types of `R` code have you tried so far? maybe include some...

Comment: @Nate I added the R code that was most useful so far, it got me halfway in terms of getting the total frequencies by subcategory. Thank you for taking the time to check on this.

Comment: Try: `dfm_select(dfm, pattern = “dict1”)`. That will give you a dfm where the features are the values in the dictionary, not the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, I believe you are in the look for the `table()` command. You need to work a little bit of regular expressions to treat the first sentence, but I believe you can do it. An idea can be as following:

```
s <-  "day after day day after day We stuck nor breath nor motion"
s <- strsplit(s, "\\s+")

dict <- list(a<- c("day", "week", "month"),
                        b<-c("breath","motion"))
lapply(dict, function(x){
                Wordsinvect<-intersect(unlist(x),unlist(s))
                return(table(s)[Wordsinvect])}
)


# [[1]]
# day 
# 4 
# 
# [[2]]
# s
# breath motion 
# 1      1
```

I hope it helps. Cheers !

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for!